# Firebase Firestore Permission Denied Error when signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want to create a node js app which downloads some data from the firestore. Although I've done everything like it's shown in tutorials I've been stuck with reading document from the firestore for hours. I have a very simple database structure with simple security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /partners/{document=**} {
        allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

In my code I just want to login into firebase using email and password and then download one document under existing path:

```
const firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/firestore");

const email = <correct email>
const password = <correct password>
var firestoreConfig = {
  ...
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firestoreConfig);
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(function(user){
  const userId = user.user.uid
  const firestore = firebase.firestore();
  console.log(`logged to firestore as  ${userId}`)
  firestore.doc("/partner/test/communication/544a3deec/messages/2e5b89b8-c48f-4d4f").get()
  .then(function(data){
    console.log(`${Object.keys(data).length}`);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  })
})
```

and the error is

```
{ FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (/Users/cb/Documents/IdeaProjects/node-hello/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1205:28)
    at fromRpcStatus (/Users/cb/Documents/IdeaProjects/node-hello/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:5246:12)
    at fromWatchChange (/Users/cb/Documents/IdeaProjects/node-hello/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:5482:35)
    at PersistentListenStream.onMessage (/Users/cb/Documents/IdeaProjects/node-hello/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15817:27)
    at /Users/cb/Documents/IdeaProjects/node-hello/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15750:30
    at /Users/cb/Documents/IdeaProjects/node-hello/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15786:28
    at /Users/cb/Documents/IdeaProjects/node-hello/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14218:20
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  code: 'permission-denied',
  name: 'FirebaseError',
  toString: [Function] }
```

I see that the login was successful because it printed out the uid of the user. What can be the issue ? Security rules or I just completely don't understand the firestore ?

EDIT:
Changed my code according to Doug answer:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firestoreConfig);
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    const userId = user.uid
    const firestore = firebase.firestore();
    console.log(`logged firestore as  ${userId}`)
    firestore.doc("/partner/test/communication/544a3deec/messages/2e5b89b8-c48f-4d4f").get()
    .then(function(data){
      console.log(`${Object.keys(data).length}`);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })
  } else {
  }
});
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
})
```

same error as before

Comment: Your code is querying subcollection under "partner", but your rules only allow queries under "partners" plural.  So, you have a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the code, an additional s for partner.